# Get the review and rating List of my app

Tags: iphone, ios6, app-store-connect

Is there any link that give me the review list of my app from iTunes store?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=APP_APPLE_ID"]];
```

APP_APPLE_ID is your Apple ID which you can get from iTunes->Manage Your Applications

Comment: yes I got it but how we get it in json format.Like this https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=APP_ID it will give us rating count but not give review list or count

Comment: You can not get list of review. You just need to redirect user to ratting page where they can read comments and can add their own.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is **now**, there wasn't a few months ago.

Simply navigate to iTunes Connect -> Manage Your Applications -> MyApp -> View Customers Ratings and Reviews (in the iTunes Links) section